# Bluetooth on VirtualBox / Wine / Bottles (for Silhouette Studio)

Tags: virtualbox, wine, bluetooth

I have just made my Silhouette Studio workable on Bottles and Virtualbox, my problem though is trying to detect the machine through Bluetooth.

On Windows VirtualBox:

- machine works through usb cable
- able to detect the Silhouette Portrait on bluetooth settings
- unable to detect the machine through bluetooth

On Botles/Wine:

- could not detect machine through usb cable nor bluetooth

Would want to use the machine on a separate table so bluetooth is the best option for me but I could not seem to make it work on either softwares. Wondering if anyone has encountered similar issues and has a fix on this.

Comment: Does this answer your question:https://superuser.com/questions/823704/difficulty-getting-universal-usb-installer-to-work-in-wine

Comment: what I wanted to mount is the bluetooth module, so i don't really know what drive i should pick on the options?

Comment: You can use the [extension pack](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/7.0.4/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-7.0.4.vbox-extpack). Double click on the file once downloaded and should open the virtualbox screen. go through the installation process and restart VirtualBox. The you are good to go.